# print the sentences of a file one after another

Tags: c

I have a text file (input.txt) with 4 paragraphs and I have to write the sentences of these paragraphs in another file (output.txt) one after another (separated by new line).

The sentences in the original file are separated by '.','!' and '?'.

I have done it but my code has a problem. Some sentences are not written in a new line in the output.txt file

My code:

```
while(1) {
    c = fgetc(fp);
    if( feof(fp) ) {
      break;
    }

    c_next = fgetc(fp);

    if( feof(fp) ) {
      fprintf(fp_output, "%c", c);
      break;
    } else {
      if( c=='.' || c=='?' || c=='!' ) {
        fprintf(fp_output, "%c\n", c);
      } else {
        if( c=='\n' ) {
          fprintf(fp_output, "%c", c_next);
        } else if( c_next=='\n' ) {
          fprintf(fp_output, "%c ", c);
        } else {
          fprintf(fp_output, "%c%c", c, c_next);
        }

      }
    }

  }
```

For example, for an input file:

```
This is the first sentence. The second one contains some more words, other words,
more words, etc. The third sentence has; and more like: this, that, those.

This is the second paragraph. And now a question? Only an exclamative
sentence is missing!

This is the third paragraph. Another component - word - would be this.
The final sentence of the paragraph!

This is the last paragraph.
```

I get the following output with my code:

```
This is the first sentence.
The second one contains some more words, other words, more words, etc. The third sentence has; and more like: this, that, those.
This is the second paragraph.
And now a question?
Only an exclamative sentence is missing!
This is the third paragraph. Another component - word - would be this.The final sentence of the paragraph!
This is the last paragraph.
```

The problem is in the second and in the sixth line.Each line must have at most 1 sentence.

Any idea or hint or solution is welcomed.

Thank you

Comment: Consider what your code will do if `c_next` is a full stop (`'.'`). The way to debug such issues is to use a debugger to step through the code line by line. Your use of `c` and `c_next` just leads to confusion. I suggest you can do it without `c_next`.

Comment: How can I do it without c_next? How do I find out when the new sentence begins? @kaylum Or just by checking if the character is uppercase?

Comment: Well, if there is a full stop then that tells you that the sentence has ended. Why do you need the next character after a full stop to know whether the sentence ends there or not? The next character is irrelevant. The full stop itself is enough.

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: @kaylum I tried to do it the way you told me to, but I could not. I would be grateful if you would show me the code. Thanks

Comment: when asking about a runtime problem, as your question is doing, post code that cleanly compiles, small, and still exhibits the problem.  The posted code does not compile

Comment: do not use the function: `feof()` to determine the end of the input file.  Rather use the returned value from the call to `fgetc()`  which will return EOF when end of the input file is encountered.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line. 2) consistently indent the code. suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  Note: consider a closing brace '}'(and preferably an opening brace '{') as a separate statement.

Comment: strongly suggest just skipping over a newline '\n' rather than printing it, because the messes up the desired output format of a single sentence per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code reads 2 char per time, but only checks the 1st char. So if c_next is ".!?", it simply fails.

**Updated. see "if(c=='\n')" part. I cant comment yet.**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

FILE* fp, *fo;
int c, flag = -1;
fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
fo = fopen("output.txt", "w");
while(fp != NULL){
  c = fgetc(fp);
  if(feof(fp)) break;

  if(c=='\n'){
    fprintf(fo, " ");
    continue;
  }

  if(flag != '.' && flag != '!' && flag != '?'){
    fprintf(fo, "%c", c);
  }
  else{
    fprintf(fo, "\n");
    if(c != ' '){
      fprintf(fo, "%c", c);
    }
  }
  flag = c;
}
fclose(fp);
fclose(fo);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but it has one problem, when a sentence in the input file is split in 2 lines and then when the 2 lines are joined together in the output.txt file, there is not space between the end of the beginning of the 2 words. Like: 
This is the second paragraph. And now a question? Only an exclamative
sentence is missing!
After joining it becomes: 
Only an exclamativesentence is missing! (no space between exclamativesentence)

Answer (score 2):

the following code:

1. has only been lightly tested
2. cleanly compiles
3. ignores multiple end of sentence markers, even if separated by white space
4. ignores newline sequences
5. ignores white space before a sentence

and now, the code

```
#include <stdio.h>  // fopen(), fclose(), fgetc(), putchar()
#include <ctype.h>  // isalpha()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define PERIOD (',')
#define QUESTION_MARK ('?')
#define EXCLAMATION_MARK ('!')

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if( 2 > argc )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <inputFileName>\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, command line parameter exists

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    if( NULL == (fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" ) ) )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    int inSentence = 0;
    int ch;
    while( EOF != (ch = fgetc( fp ) ) )
    {
        if( inSentence )
        {
            putchar( ch );
            if( PERIOD == ch || EXCLAMATION_MARK == ch || QUESTION_MARK == ch)
            {
                inSentence = 0;
                putchar( '\n' );
            }
        }

        else // if( !inSentence )
        {
            if( isalpha( ch ) )
            { // then not white space nor more punctuation
                inSentence = 1;
                putchar( ch );
            }
        }
    } // end while

    // cleanup
    if( inSentence )
    {
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    fclose( fp );
} // end function: main
```